# Passage in Bible saying: Every morning I wake up a new person?

Tags: bible

There is a passage in the New Testament that says, I paraphrase:  Every morning I wake up a new person. Or: Every morning I am born a new man. I think Apostle Peter or Apostle Paul is speaking it. Can someone help me track the exact quote with textual reference? Thanks.

Comment: I don't remember that. The nearest I can think of is [Lam 3:23](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lamentations+3:23&version=NIV1984), otherwise chck out [this list](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=+new+morning&qs_version=NIV1984).

Comment: It could be: „Everyday I am born a new man”, it is very hard to find it by keywords, I recall it from my childhood and in those times didn't knew English, I am a native Romanian. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @Wikis It may be this, but since is so long ago, my memory failed me, an I put it in the New Testament. I better do my reading and study.

Comment: @eduard you may wish to try bible gateway's Romanian concordance.

Comment: Lamentations 3:23 ... your compassions are new every morning.  Pauls says, "I die daily"...

Comment: @Narnian Yes that is, I think. Do you know exactly where it says so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of **2 Corinthians 5:17 (KJV)**

> 17 Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things
>   are passed away; behold, all things are become new.

It's not "every morning" but it is the passage that comes to mind with the teaching that we are made new.  It deals with out new relationship in Christ after salvation.

In the Old Testament, there is **Lamentations 3:22-23 (KJV)**

> 22 It is of the Lord's mercies that we are not consumed, because his
>   compassions fail not.
>
> 23 They are new every morning: great is thy faithfulness.

If neither of these are what you're thinking of, you can search many versions of the Bible at http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lamentations+3%3A22-23&version=KJV

Comment: It maybe also: `1 Peter 1:23` 
`1 Peter 2:2`
`2 Peter 1:19` Thanks, +1, accept, lam 3:23 is really powerful, is good to know something good is renewing there every-morning.

Answer (score 1):

Here is where Paul says, "I die every day."

> I protest, brothers, by my pride in you, which I have in Christ Jesus
>   our Lord, **I die every day**! 1 Corinthians 15:31

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the passage, I don't know why I remebered it as being reborn again. +1

Answer (score 1):

2nd Corinthians 5:17 is all you need to be concerned about. It is every second every day thing that takes place in Christ.

Comment: ? This doesn't seem to answer the question more than any of the other questions... If you would like to contribute please expound and _add_ to the other questions. For more on how to answer a question, please view [this link](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).